# Clickhouse - Group by within nested columns

Tags: grouping, clickhouse

How do I perform *group by* within nested columns?

I have a nested column *items.productName* and *items.amount*.

I want to get the sum of amounts grouped by each value of *productName*.

I am able to achieve this using *array join*

```sql
    SELECT items.productName as name, sum(items.amount) as amt from test 
    array join items
    group by items.productName
```

But *array joins* are slow so we cannot use them.

So I tried using *sumForEach()* but I am not sure how to group the result by individual productName

```sql
    SELECT items.productName as name, sumForEach(items.amount) as amt from test
    group by name
```

Can I achieve this functionality without using *array join*?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative can be used [sumMap](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql_reference/aggregate_functions/reference/#agg_functions-summap)-function:

```sql
select result.1 as name, result.2 as amt
from (
      select sumMap(items.productName, items.amount) sum_per_keys,
            arrayJoin(arrayZip(sum_per_keys.1, sum_per_keys.2)) result
      from nested_columns_test)
order by name;
```

Testing for CH 20.3.8.53 shows that **sumMap** much *slower* than **array join**.

---

Prepare test environment:

```sql
create table nested_columns_test(
  id Int32,
  items Nested(productName String, amount Int32)
) Engine = MergeTree()
order by (id);

insert into nested_columns_test
select number as id,
      arrayMap(x -> concat('product_', toString(x)), range(number % 32)) as `items.productName`, 
      arrayMap(x -> number + x, range(number % 32)) as `items.amount` 
from numbers(100*1000*1000);

SELECT items.productName as name, sum(items.amount) as amt 
from nested_columns_test 
array join items
group by items.productName
order by name;
```